# How can I make a MySQL Script to run automatically whenever a the MySQL Server reboots on a Linux environment

Tags: mysql, bash

I'd like to automatically populate Memory tables each time the MySQL Server reboots. Is there a way I can set a trigger which is based on that event? Or a script which is run by either the Mysqd or mysqld_safe startup scripts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can run a script with crontab with `@reboot` as condition.

Comment: Hi Ferd, doesnt @reboot kick only when the whole host server reboots? I want it to run even after one runs the command:    service mysql restart

Comment: Ah right, I understood you referring to the server rebooting, misread it, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below startup script for linux :
add the followin in init.d file.
vi /etc/init.d/ you have to set it executable with: chmod +x /etc/init.d/start_my_app And dont forget to add #!/bin/sh on top of that file

And put the complete location of your script in it, like /var/myscripts/test.php instead of just start_my_app

in test.php page you can have mysql query executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a command line option "--init-file=file_name" whenever mysql start

--init-file=file_name

Command-Line Format --init-file=file_name

Option-File Format  init-file

Read SQL statements from this file at startup. Each statement must be on a single line and should not include comments.

This option is unavailable if MySQL was configured with the --disable-grant-options option.

Source : Mysql developer Documentation

For More Detail 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file